# Set particular array values as array key from multiple values

Tags: php, arrays

I want to set array particular value to it's key, suppose I am having array like below :

```
$temp =  [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => 1
            [hash_id] => 
            [requested_user_amount] => 7250.88
            [requested_user_id] => 9
            [requested_user_rate] => 49800
            [requested_user_qty] => 0.1456

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => 1
            [hash_id] => 
            [requested_user_amount] => 64740
            [requested_user_id] => 12
            [requested_user_rate] => 49800
            [requested_user_qty] => 1.3
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [type] => 1
            [hash_id] => 
            [requested_user_amount] => 5000
            [requested_user_id] => 17
            [requested_user_rate] => 49800
            [requested_user_qty] => 0.100401606
      )
```

And I want to set `requested_user_id` to array key.

I found one solution like below

```
 array_column($temp, null, 'requested_user_id');
```

**Output :**

```
[9] => Array
            (
                [type] => 1
                [hash_id] => 
                [requested_user_amount] => 7250.88
                [requested_user_id] => 9
                [requested_user_rate] => 49800
                [requested_user_qty] => 0.1456

            )

        [12] => Array
            (
                [type] => 1
                [hash_id] => 
                [requested_user_amount] => 64740
                [requested_user_id] => 12
                [requested_user_rate] => 49800
                [requested_user_qty] => 1.3
            )
        [17] => Array
            (
                [type] => 1
                [hash_id] => 
                [requested_user_amount] => 5000
                [requested_user_id] => 17
                [requested_user_rate] => 49800
                [requested_user_qty] => 0.100401606
          )
```

And it'll give exact output which I want. but problem is function `array_column` requires php 5.5 and my server is 5.4.

From searching the web I found `array_map()` is the alternative function of `array_column()`, and I tried also but it does not give same output.

**array_map code :**

```
array_map(function($element){return $element;}, $temp,'requested_user_id');
```

How can I pass value as key in array_map, or is there an alternative function I can use?

Comment: Just throwing it out there, but would it not be possible to upgrade to a newer version of php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Finally I got solution, array_walk() is the function which help me out see below code which give me same output and I can say alternative or array_column() in particular my case :

Code :

```
array_walk($temp, function (&$value,$key) use (&$result) {
                            $result[ $value['requested_user_id'] ] = $value;
                        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way, Created a new array using `$temp` array, While creating
that array, use the `requested_user_id` as key.

```
$data = array();

foreach($temp as $row){
    $data[$row['requested_user_id']] = $row;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

As a function,

```
function registeredUserArray($temp){
    $data = array();
    foreach($temp as $row){
        $data[$row['requested_user_id']] = $row;
    }
    return $data;
}

$data = registeredUserArray($temp);
```

Comment: Thansk for the answer but I want it using function if possible

Answer (score 1):

use `array_map()` like this:

```
$array = array_map(function($temp){
            return array(
                $temp['requested_user_id'] => $temp
            );
        }, $temp);
```

here the the demo:

```
<?php
$temp =  array(array
        (
            'type' => 1,
            'hash_id' =>null,
            'requested_user_amount' => 7250.88,
            'requested_user_id' => 9,
            'requested_user_rate' => 49800,
            'requested_user_qty' => 0.1456

        ),
        array
        (
            'type' => 1,
            'hash_id' => null,
            'requested_user_amount' => 64740,
            'requested_user_id' => 12,
            'requested_user_rate' => 49800,
            'requested_user_qty' => 1.3
        ),
         array
        (
            'type' => 1,
            'hash_id' =>null,
            'requested_user_amount' => 5000,
            'requested_user_id' => 17,
            'requested_user_rate' => 49800,
            'requested_user_qty' => 0.100401606
        )
        );
$array = array_map(function($temp){
            return array(
                $temp['requested_user_id'] => $temp
            );
        }, $temp);
echo json_encode($array);
```

and the output:

```
[{"9":{"type":1,"hash_id":null,"requested_user_amount":7250.88,"requested_user_id":9,"requested_user_rate":49800,"requested_user_qty":0.1456}},{"12":{"type":1,"hash_id":null,"requested_user_amount":64740,"requested_user_id":12,"requested_user_rate":49800,"requested_user_qty":1.3}},{"17":{"type":1,"hash_id":null,"requested_user_amount":5000,"requested_user_id":17,"requested_user_rate":49800,"requested_user_qty":0.100401606}}]
```

Comment: @Codebrekers you need change the $temp to your format

Comment: Sorry it's not working, the output will be totally different then yours

Comment: @Codebrekers I make the demo test.php and run php test.php, it works.

Comment: Kindly provide jsfiddle link

Comment: @Codebrekers just save the code as test.php, and run it with php test.php command.    I cannot make the php runable in the jsfiddle.

Comment: Yes, I checked but it'll give different output, kindly check it again it'll generate array into array with requested_user_id key but not update actual array, I want to update actual array please check my output array and compare with yours